# Can HTML sitemaps be listed in robots.txt just like XML sitemaps?

Tags: seo, sitemap, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I will have two sitemaps for my website. The first sitemap is the **.xml** version for the search engines.  The second sitemap is a **sitemap.php** on my website for the users.

I know I can list the **sitemap.xml** in the **robots.txt** file as follows:

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Can I list **sitemap.php** in the **robots.txt**?  Will it be read by the search engines?

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.php
```

Or would it be best to let Google/Bing etc. find **sitemap.php**, when and if it gets to the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I list sitemap.php in the robots.txt?

No, that wouldn't work. The XML Sitemap goes in `robots.txt`. The public-facing site map will be crawled by search engines like any other page.

Comment: You can have your sitemap.xml file displayed as HTML though. This can be done using the extensible stylesheet language transformations (XSLT), which is [shown here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp).

Comment: @ub3rst4r, I looked up the link, thanks for the info, good to know ;-)